# How to create a scheduler for updating a boolean value using Rules?

Tags: entities, rules

I am displaying a boolean value as 'New' along with published content title.

Now I need like, the 'New' tag should be displayed for a period (ex: 3 months). After this period I need that content as it is, but 'New' tag should be removed.

[image: click here to see 'New' tag]

Answer (score 0):

It's defined in node.module like follows

```
define('NODE_NEW_LIMIT', REQUEST_TIME - 30 * 24 * 60 * 60);
```

AFAIK, you can't redefine this value. I think you need to change and use your value in all the places.

I'll check and If I found better option I'll update my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your boolean variable used to display that "*Nieuw*" (= the Dutch for "New", right?) is actually implemented via a custom (boolean) field that you added to each relevant content type. Let's assume its machine name is `field_nieuw_ja_nee`. If my assumption is wrong, at least that's a way you could configure it also.

Based on that assumption, here is a blueprint of how to make it work:

#### Step 1 - Create a Rules Component

- **Parameter**: a node (for the node to be processed).
- **Rules Action**: "set a data value", related to the `field_nieuw_ja_nee` field of the node, and set the value so that it matches with your requirement "new tag should be removed" (probably just set the boolean to 0).
- Use the Rules UI to **unit test** this Rules Component, by clicking on the "execute" link (to the right of the Rules Component), to be sure your Rules Component works as you want (and to avoid you have to wait for 3 months to see if it works as designed ...).

#### Step 2 - Create a rule to schedule the Rules Component

- **Rules Event**: After saving a new node.
- **Rules Condition**: Check if the entity has field `field_nieuw_ja_nee` (we don't want to waste time on nodes that don't have such boolean field).
- **Rules Action**: Schedule the execution of a Rules Component from step 1, to have it executed "3 months after the node was saved".